# Setting the action on rasa restart

Tags: rasa, rasa-core, rasa-x

Hi I'm trying to set some message to be uttered when the user restart the conversation. I have [asked](https://forum.rasa.com/t/how-to-utter-something-after-conversation-is-restarted/33274)
in Rasa Forum and tried to change the code. But it returned this error

> AttributeError: ‘Tracker’ object has no attribute ‘utter_message’

This is the code that I wrote:

```
class ActionRestarted(Action):
""" This is for restarting the chat"""

def name(self) -> Text:
    return "action_restart"

async def run(
        self,
        tracker: Tracker,
        dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
        domain: Dict[Text, Any],) -> List[Event]:
    from rasa.core.events import Restarted

    # only utter the template if it is available
    evts = await super().run(tracker, domain, dispatcher.utter_message("Restarted"))
    return evts + [Restarted()]
```

Feel free to point out my mistake and correct them thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass the return value of `utter_message` as the `dispatcher` parameter of `super.run()`, where it expects a `CollectingDispatcher` object.

You can just call `utter_message` from your `run` method.

```py
async def run(
        self,
        tracker: Tracker,
        dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
        domain: Dict[Text, Any],) -> List[Event]:
    from rasa.core.events import Restarted

    dispatcher.utter_message("Restarted")
    return [Restarted()]
```

Comment: Hi I have tried your solution but it gave me this error  *File "C:\EDARAN_FAQ_CHATBOT\actions.py", line 82, in run
    dispatcher.utter_message("Restarted")
AttributeError: 'Tracker' object has no attribute 'utter_message'*

Comment: Tracker doesnt have a `utter_message` but the dispatcher has. your code most likely has a typo.